# Assumptions to ensure that ratio of a function is less than ratio of first derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, inequality, curvature, functional-inequalities

I would like an increasing function $\phi: D \to \mathbb{R}_{++}$, where $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary for now, to have the property that for any $a, b \in D$ with $a < b$,

$$\frac{ \phi'(a)}{ \phi(a)} \leq \frac{ \phi'(b)}{\phi(b)} $$

For example, this occurs when $\phi$ is the exponential function. Are there any minimum conditions I can place on $\phi$ to ensure that this occurs? For example, regarding its concavity or convexity? Curvature restrictions on their own do not seem sufficient but I am not sure what else to include.

Totally fine to put restrictions on $D$ or on anything else about the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{ \phi'(a)}{ \phi(a)} \leq \frac{ \phi'(b)}{\phi(b)}
\implies
(\ln(\phi(a)))' \le (\ln(\phi(b)))'
\implies
(\ln(\phi(a)))'' \ge 0
$.

So $\ln(\phi(x))$
is convex.

Note that this requires
that $\phi(x) > 0$.